# Combining two arrays into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays one with label date i.e [Date, Date, Date ...]  and

the other with the actual date data  i.e [2021-11-26, 2021-11-25, ...].

I want to combine these two arrays such that I get array of objects such as [ { Date: 2021-11-26}, {Date:2021-11-25}, {..}, ...].

I have tried these two methods

```
obj = {};

for (var i = 0, l = date_label.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    obj[date_label[i]] = data_date[i]
}
console.log(obj);
```

and

```
_.zipObject(date_label, data_date);
```

However it only ends up giving me the last date of my data set, in an object data structure ie    { Date: 1999-11-24}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys inside an object / associative array are unique. Your `obj` is such a thing. If you turn it into a regular array and push new objects into it, it will work.

```
const obj = [];
for (let i = 0, l = date_label.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj.push({[date_label[i]]: data_date[i]})
}
console.log(obj);
```

You should probably assert that both your arrays have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

with array reduce
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
var myFinalArray = data_date.reduce(
(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => ({ 
    currentValue: date_label[currentIndex]
}), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues you are facing is that your date_label are the same and the loop are replacing the dates on the same label, again and again, you just need to change the label name and give unique to each one or you change them into the loop as well like this (obj[date_label[i] + str(i)] = data_date[i]).

```
date_label = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3', .....]

obj = {};

for (var i = 0, l = date_label.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    obj[date_label[i]] = data_date[i]
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

obj is of type array not object.
data_date needs to be in string format.

```
for(var i= 0; i<data_date.length-1;i++) {
obj.push({"Date":date_date[i]}) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello *AshleyCrasto*,

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Sol : Well, the other members have given solution on how to achieve the desired result. I will emphasize on why you are getting the single object.

> it only ends up giving me the last date of my data set, in an object data structure ie { Date: 1999-11-24}

You need to understand how references work in JavaScript. Heres the catch,

As the values in *date_label* are all same

> [Date, Date, Date ...]

When you use,

```
obj[date_label[i]] = data_date[i]
```

Everytime, it get executed the same key value will be keep updating instead of creating new key and new value. Because the same values holds same reference.

*So, first time {"date" : "somevalue"} will be there, then
second time {"date" : "somevalue2"}, the value of key "date" will be updated
with new value. This is due to same key.*

Therefore, you need to take of this thing. For your better understanding here is my code: (same as others but elaborately)

```
const date_label = ["date","date"]
const data_date = [2021-11-26, 2021-11-25]

function returnObj(label, value){
//this will return a new object with provided label and value.
    const Obj =  {};
    Obj[label] = value
    return Obj
}
let listOfObjects = []
for(let i=0 ; i< date_label.length ; i++){
//new object will be added to list.
    const obj = returnObj(date_label[i],data_date[i])
    listOfObjects.push(obj)
}

console.log(listOfObjects)
```